# jQuery UI Slider updating step attribute but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I am using a jQuery range slider plugin named [asRange](https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asRange#examples)

It's working quite alright, but when I am updating the *step* attribute with a conditional statement, it's updating the value in the DOM alright but not quite working as expected. I need the step value to be "0.001" when the range value is less than 1 and step to be "1" when the range value is more than 1.

If you examine the DOM elements with the developer tools, you will see the step value is updating properly, but not working as it should.

I have been trying on it for hours now. Couldn't find anything. Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

```
            <input class="range-slider" type="range" min="0.007" max="10" name="price" step="0.001" />
            <script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".range-slider").asRange();

                $(".range-slider").on('asRange::change', function (e) {
                var val = $(".range-slider").asRange('get');

                  if (val > 1) 
              {
                  $(".range-slider").attr("step" , "1");
              }
              else if (val <= 1) 
              {
                  $(".range-slider").attr("step" , "0.001");
              }


              });
              });
            </script>
```

Comment: not sure this is actually a JQueryUI widget. may want to remove that tag.

Comment: reading the documentation for that plugin you found, i'm not sure you can change the options such as step once it is initially set. it doesn't seem to have a method for doing so (just changing the tag attributes is not usually how you would change options for a JQuery widget, since we have no idea how the code uses those attributes, if at all. you would usually do something like `$(widgetSelector).slider( 'step', 1 );`). you might want to check out JQueryUI, the official set of UI plugins for JQuery. I know that their slider has the ability to set step after initial creation.

Comment: the `step` can be updated using the update method. https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asRange/blob/master/src/asRange.js#L241 https://jsfiddle.net/rqk0297t/ The source is usually the best documentation.

Comment: @KevinB You're awesome! You're right, should've checked in the source first. But really thanks for this. But that sort of created another issue, now the bubble is showing NaN instead of the range value. You can check in the site link. Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Okay, just updated the value as well on the conditional statement `$(".range-slider").asRange('update', {value:val});` and it's working! Though all this workarounds is making the code bluff, maybe I should go for the plain slider @dqhendricks mentioned. But in any case, Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the update method of the library instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".range-slider").asRange();

  $(".range-slider").on('asRange::change', function(e) {
    var val = $(".range-slider").asRange('get');

    if (val > 1) {
      $(".range-slider").asRange('update', { step: 1 }); // Here
    } else if (val <= 1) {
      $(".range-slider").asRange('update', { step: 0.001 }); // And Here
    }
  });
});
```

The DOM element is no more updating the object asRange, then, when you change the DOM element, the asRange created object will not be reflected.

Comment: I see. It's the working solution but it gives NaN to the value bubble. So just adding `$(".range-slider").asRange('update', {value:val});` inside every conditional statements fixes the issue.